How can we load and select the meshes(Child nodes) of glb file using Sceneform Android?
I have been trying to implement a 3D model viewer with mesh selection by referring to this project - https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android/tree/master/samples/3d-model-viewer.
Unfortunately, I am not able to get the child entity click on click listeners.
Here is my code
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main){ /*GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {*/

private lateinit var sceneView: SceneView
private lateinit var loadingView: View
private lateinit var modelInstance: ModelInstance

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    sceneView = view.findViewById(R.id.sceneView)
    loadingView = view.findViewById(R.id.loadingView)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {

        val modelFile = "models/truck.glb"
        modelInstance = sceneView.modelLoader.createModelInstance(modelFile)

    val modelNode = ModelNode(
            modelInstance = modelInstance,
            centerOrigin = Position(x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f)
        )
        modelNode.scale = Scale(.025f)
    sceneView.addChildNode(modelNode)
    modelNode.nodes[0].scale
//        sceneView.onGestureListener = this
        sceneView.onTouchEvent = { e,hitresult ->
            Log.e("TAG", "onViewCreated: ", )
            false
        }
        loadingView.isGone = true
    }

In this hitresult always returns me the main entity, not the child entity. How can we get the child entity to do some modification to the specific clicked area?


Did you find a solution to this?

@AzadeFarshad I have taken each parts as separate glb file and added to sceneview this way.    sceneView.addChildNodes(nodeModels.values.toList())
